# DirectX 8 Win32 GUI Not Appearing/Flickering While Running

Tags: graphics, c, windows

I am programming a game with DirectX 8, and I am trying to use the GUI options that are provided by the Win32 window that I am using. However, when I try to render a button or, in this case, a textbox to the screen, I am unsuccessful. I remember previously being able to get one to render for like 0.5 seconds, but then it would disappear.

What could be the reason for this? What could I have done wrong with the setup of the window?

```
 WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_CLASSDC, MsgProc, 0L, 0L, 
                      GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                      "Engine", NULL };
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "EEXIcon.ico", IMAGE_ICON,
        0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "EEXIcon.ico", IMAGE_ICON,
        0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );
    
    // Create the application's window



    hWnd = CreateWindow( "Engine", "Engine", WS_CAPTION, 100, 100, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL );
```

Here is the DirectX setup

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = d3ddm.Format;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

//d3dpp.FullScreen_PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
if (fullscreen)
{
    d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 800;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 600;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;//D3DFMT_R5G6B5;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 3;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D24S8;
    d3dpp.FullScreen_PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
}
```

And finally, here is the GUI instance I was trying to create:

```
//hWndEditBox defined earlier in the file as a HWND
hWndEditBox = CreateWindow("EDIT","Edit Boxes",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,10,10,100,50,hWnd,(HMENU)IDC_EDITBOX_TEXT,(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),NULL);
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the best forum to get an answer to this question. You might be better asking on Stackoverflow. But you'll probably need to explain why you are using DirectX 8 which is quite old.

Comment: "Quite old", yeah. Not exactly retrocomputing.

Comment: DirectX 8.1 is the highest version released for Windows 98. Does it not count?

Comment: I'd say DX8 is retro - we all know the term is subjective at best, but when it comes to things like graphics APIs, they move fast, and DX8 is pretty far removed from current GPU and API architectures. Still, I do feel like you're more likely to get a better answer on SO.

Comment: This is the win32 api, so do you also need to call ShowWindow() at the end?

Comment: @JeremyP I submitted this for a retro game programming jam contest. It qualified there, as it could, in theory, be compiled in Windows 98, although compiling in Windows 98 was only done for the first part of the jam because I did not like how I couldn't run the game inside the virtual machine I am using (it is in VMWare).

Comment: @rjhwinner03 The fact that something qualifies at some non related contest is not really a support for it being on topic here. Even more so if the task on hand is only theoretically done on an on topic system. Next there is much code missing, do you do a ShowWindow()? Or why there is a menue when it's a WS_CHILD? Last, but most important, from the information presented it seems like a generic Windows programming issue than anything specific for W98/DX8.

Comment: @Raffzahn I do a ShowWindow() funciton. I have the following: ShowWindow(hWndEditBox, SW_SHOW);

Comment: You should try to post this on https://stackoverflow.com/ even if its old there are still guys like me that still remembers some of the old tech someone might even throw working code at you there ... just make sure you chose good title and tags so the right people see your question

Comment: Are you displaying 3D graphics *in the same place where the controls are*? I don't think Windows protects your window from drawing over the top of its child windows.

Comment: @user253751 yeah, that is what the issue is. I do not know how to prevent that, unfortunately.

Comment: @rjhwinner03 You could put the 3D graphics in a separate child window from the other controls

Comment: @user253751 I don't know how to do that. Do you have a link or something explaining it?

Comment: @user253751 Actually, doing some more research, I really just want the text boxes, buttons, etc. to overlap.